# How to remove a element from HTML when it is added to a another div

Tags: jquery, html

when clicked on a Checkbox , i am adding the response HTML to another DIV called as ordersdiv.

My question is that how to remove the checkbox when it is added to the  ordersdiv

So that it appears without checkbox inside ordersdiv ??

http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/7/

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
    $("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/9/)**

Use jQuery **[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```
$("#ordersdiv .checkboxclas").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you very much , this worked , the checkboxes aren't getting displayed .

Comment: @PreethiJain Try this http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/14/, no need to remove anything..!

Answer (score 0):

Use `detach()` and `appendTo()`

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").detach();
    $(divdata).appendTo("#ordersdiv");
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/11/)

or Just `appendTo()`

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $("div.activateUiHTML").appendTo("#ordersdiv");
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide/remove the check box from the html inside the `ordersdiv`

Here is the modified code

```
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
    $("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
    $('#ordersdiv .checkboxclas').hide();  //use .remove() to remove the checkbox
});
```

And the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/15/)